# Redis Cluster with Lettuce does not update IP list after nodes reboot

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis, redis-cluster

I have a Redis Cluster (3 leaders and 3 followers), when I restart all cluster nodes I would like the application to automatically identify that an IP exchange has happened.

In the application I'm using spring applying the following settings:

spring.redis.cluster.nodes: redis:6379
spring.lettuce.cluster.refresh.adaptive: true

It's as if the application was caching the old ip addresses, I need to somehow get this list of nodes updated, I'm connecting to a dns.

Answer (score 2):

"Refresh adaptive" setting in my case is misspelled, lacking the term "redis".

Correct setting is: spring.redis.lettuce.cluster.refresh.adaptive

Answer (score 0):

This maybe help you I think.

```
enablePeriodicRefresh()
```

https://lettuce.io/core/release/reference/#clientoptions.cluster-specific-options